# Median Split of one variable to create another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, split, median

I am currently struggling with a median split in R studio. I wish to create a new column in my data frame which is a median split of another, however, I do not know how this can be accomplished. Any and all help will be appreciated. this is the code I have previously run:

```
medianpcr <- median(honourswork$PCR.x)
highmedian <- filter(honourswork, PCR.x <= medianpcr)
lowmedian <- filter(honourswork, PCR.x > medianpcr)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you post a question on SO, it's always a good idea to include an example dataframe so that the answerer doesn't have to create one themselves.

Onto your question, if I understand you correctly, you can use the `mutate()` and `case_when()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
# Load the dplyr library
library(dplyr)

# Create an example dataframe
data <- data.frame(
  rowID = c(1:20),
  value = runif(20, 0, 50)
)

# Use case_when to mutate a new column 'category' with values based on 
# the 'value' column
data2 <- data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(category = 
    dplyr::case_when(
      value > median(value) ~ "Highmedian",
      value < median(value) ~ "Lowmedian",
      value == median(value) ~ "Median"
    )
  )
```

More about [case_when()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) here.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create some data:

```
set.seed(123)
honourswork <- data.frame(PCR.x = rnorm(100))
```

In dplyr, you might do:

```
library(tidyverse)
honourswork %>% mutate(medianpcr = median(PCR.x)) %>% 
mutate(highmedian = ifelse(PCR.x > medianpcr, 1, 0)) -> honourswork
            
honourswork %>% mutate(medianpcr = median(PCR.x)) %>%
mutate(lowmedian = ifelse(PCR.x <= medianpcr, 1, 0)) -> honourswork
```

Equivalently in base R:

```
honourswork$highmedian <- 0
honourswork$highmedian[honourswork$PCR.x > median(honourswork$PCR.x)] <- 1

honourswork$lowmedian <- 0
honourswork$lowmedian[honourswork$PCR.x <= median(honourswork$PCR.x)] <- 1
```

Comment: thank you otto, is there a way I can attach this new list to my existing data frame? I cannot see it in the data frame.

Comment: @waqarmohiuddin - see my edits